# How can I Remove/Add a specific object on PowerShell output

Tags: azure, powershell

I have automated the process of creating custom rules on Azure Application Gateway WAF. However, whenever I update any existing custom rule, it automatically removes all other custom rules. I have been unable to find a specific command in the Azure PowerShell documentation to update individual custom rules. I have also raised this issue with Microsoft, and they have confirmed that the command is not available in Azure PowerShell.

During my research, I discovered that we can achieve this by using the ".Add" and ".Remove" operations. However, I am encountering some errors while attempting to do so.

Currently, I am trying two approaches:

1. Adding new malicious IPs to the specific existing custom rule. When I try to execute this, I receive the following error message:

   ```
   PS C:\Users\japuthiyakath> $policy = Get-AzApplicationGatewayFirewallPolicy -Name $policyName -ResourceGroupName $policyRG
   PS C:\Users\japuthiyakath> (($policy.CustomRules | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "IPRestrict"}).MatchConditions.MatchValues).Add('2.3.6.9')
   MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "Add" with "1" argument(s): "Collection was of a fixed size."
   ```
2. Remove the IPRestrict custom rule from the firewall policy and replace it with a modified custom rule. The approach of working well using `.RemoveAt(0)`, but we might encounter difficulties in determining the exact position of the object to be removed.

   I attempted to remove the object using the command provided below, but despite the absence of any errors, the object remains unaffected and does not get removed.

   ```
   PS C:\Users\japuthiyakath> ($policy.CustomRules | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "IPRestrict"}).Remove
   ```

For Reference;

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>As an aside: `Where-Object Name -eq IPRestrict` rather than `Where-Object {$_.Name -match "IPRestrict"}` is used below to identify the policy of interest: [`-eq`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-eq) ensures literal, full-value matching, whereas [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) also finds *substrings* (by way of a [*regex*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) pattern). Separately, the omission of `{ ... }` and `$_` is an application of [simplified syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Simplified_Syntax).</sup>

Re 1:

- It isn't obvious, but your command applies [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration), because the `.MatchConditions` and also the `.MatchValues` property contain *lists* (array-like collections of type [`` System.Collections.Generic.List`1 ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.List-1)).
- Due to the resulting member-access enumeration, `.MatchConditions.MatchValues` returns a *regular .NET array* ([`System.Array`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Array)) containing the `.MatchValues` list entries across all `.MatchCondition` list entries.

  - .NET arrays are *fixed-size* data structures, and only implement an `.Add()` method in the context of implementing the [`IList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IList) interface.
  - Calling this - unsupported by arrays - method results in the exception you saw: "Collection was of a fixed size".
- To successfully extend the *list* stored in `.MatchValues` (which *does* support `.Add()`), you either need to identify which particular `.MatchConditions` list entry you want to target or you must iterate over *all* `.MatchConditions` list entries and call `.Add()` *on each* (assuming that makes sense); e.g.:

```bash
# Target the *first* .MatchCondition list element
($policy.CustomRules | Where-Object Name -eq IPRestrict).MatchConditions[0].
  MatchValues.Add('2.3.6.9')

# Target *all* .MatchCondition list elements (don't know if that makes sense)
($policy.CustomRules | Where-Object Name -eq IPRestrict).MatchConditions |
  ForEach-Object { $_.MatchValues.Add('2.3.6.9') }
```

Re 2:

The [`` System.Collections.Generic.List`1 ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.List-1) type has a `.Remove()` method that allows you to pass the *object* to remove from the list rather than having to know its *index in the list*:

```bash
$ruleToRemove = $policy.CustomRules | Where-Object Name -eq IPRestrict
$policy.CustomRules.Remove($ruleToRemove)
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolution:

To update the existing policy of the Web Application Firewall (WAF), please use the following command:

```
$NewIPRestrictRule = New-AzApplicationGatewayFirewallCustomRule -Name $customRuleName -Priority $customRulePriority -RuleType MatchRule -MatchCondition $condition -Action Block
$policy = Get-AzApplicationGatewayFirewallPolicy -Name $policyName -ResourceGroupName $policyRG
$ruleToRemove = $policy.CustomRules | Where-Object Name -eq $customRuleName
$policy.CustomRules.Remove($ruleToRemove)
$policy.CustomRules.Add($NewIPRestrictRule)
Set-AzApplicationGatewayFirewallPolicy -InputObject $policy
```